# How to change marker in a MapView after doing a on Click in an Adapter in Android?

Tags: android

So, I'm using an Adapter to give me locations around my current location via the Google places API. Thus, I've both the MapView and ListView in the same layout. Now, I want to change the marker location to any location that the user chooses form the list of places displayed in the list view. I am not able to understand how do I manage that? How can I pass values from the Adapter to the Activity so that the marker in the MapView changes its position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using fragments, there is an example at the bottom of this page that explains how to do this from a ListFragment to a separate "DetailFragment:"

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

But basically what I would do is use

```
@Override 
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Do something when a list item is clicked
}
```

to get the id or position of the item in the ListView, and using that id get the corresponding coordinates for the MapView. If you have all the data stored in your adapter class, you could create a method called getCoords(long id) or getCoords(int position) or something like that to call in onListItemClick.